# NodeJS, ExpressJS: Why POST parameters in request are persistent

Tags: node.js, post, express, httprequest

I am getting started with Node/Express and was trying out some code understand POST requests. I have the following code:

```
app.post('/:username', function(req, res)
{
    if(req.isAuthenticated())
    {
        console.log("POST from autheticated users");
        console.log(req.param("Operation"));
        console.log(req.param("Value"));
    }
    else
    {
        console.log("POST from guest user");
        console.log(req.param("Operation"));
        console.log(req.param("Value"));
    }
});
```

And I use Webstorms REST Client to send the following POST request:

http: //localhost:8080/user1?Operation=op1&Value=1

I sent few POST request with different Operation and Values and this is what was printed out:

```
POST from guest user 

[ 'op1', 'op1' ]

[ '1', '1' ]

POST from guest user

[ 'op1', 'op1', 'op2' ]

[ '1', '1', '2' ]

POST from guest user

[ 'op1', 'op1', 'op2', 'op3' ]

[ '1', '1', '2', '3' ]
```

Why are the POST parameters are saved across requests? And what is the way to get only the current parameters? I'm sorry if this is a very fundamental concept in POST.

Comment: This didn't seem right to me, so I tried it, and I do not get what your'e getting.  I get a singular value, as expected, so it makes me wonder what else is going on in your app file.  The way `req.params` behaves is not different for POST than it is in GET, by the way.  Also, I recommend using `req.query` instead of `req.params` for clarity's sake.  `req.params` mashes together route parameters, the POST body, and querystring parameters.

Comment: Thanks Ethan. I'm not sure why this is. I have only two POST routes in my app. Wondering if its because of using the REST Client of Webstorm. Will check again.